# "Move to Trash" fails silently on "XYZ is damaged and can't be opened"

Tags: trash, docker

I'm getting this error repeatedly on my new M2 after using the migration assistant from my Intel mac.

[image]

Here's the problem:

- It pops back up immediately no matter what I click
- The error comes back even if I hit "Move to Trash"

I don't know how to find where the Docker application it's talking about. I've already uninstalled Docker.

`$ ls /Applications | grep Docker # returns nothing`

There is a greyed out "DockerHelper" in the Activity Monitor but it's not using any resources and and I can't kill it. I'm not sure if it's somewhere on disk still, but I haven't found it yet.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by emptying the Trash. The file was already in the Trash but Apple's security process was stuck in some sort of unhandled state I guess.

Emptying the Trash gave me one final warning saying "Please manually move this file to the trash" then it disappeared and the error ceased.